# Запрос подтверждения при нажатии кнопки - Bootstrap 3, AngularJS

Tags: bootstrap, angularjs

Сейчас по нажатию кнопки при помощи `ng-click` вызывается метод из контроллера для `AngularJS`. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии той же кнопки пользователю выдавалось окно с вопросом, при нажатии `Да` - функция из `ng-click` выполнялась, при нажатии `Нет` - просто закрывалось диалоговое окно?
При этом в функцию передается параметр.
Смотрел `bootstrap-modal`, 
попытался сделать что-то вроде

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'confirm_delete_item.html',
        controller: 'modalDialogCtrl'
});
```

Отдельный контроллер для модальных окон, и при `ng-click` на кнопку в функции создается модальное окно.

Но на сервере все url обрабатываются согласно маскам, и `confirm_delete_item.html` необходимо прописывать дополнительно. Это всего лишь простейшее диалоговое окно `Да-нет`, поэтому, как мне показалось, такой вариант не очень рационален. Прописывать html-код диалогового окна в js файле тоже не хотелось бы.

Есть ли более простой и быстрый способ реализовать данную задачу средствами `AngularJS`?

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает вариант положить шаблон модального окна в вёрстку `<script id="confirm_delete_item.html" type="text/ng-template">...шаблон...</script>`? [Доки](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModal'];

function MainCtrl($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.open = function(param) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'confirm_delete_item.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: 'sm',
      resolve: {
        param: function() {
          // передаём параметр в контроллер модального окна "ModalInstanceCtrl"
          return param;
        }
      }
    });
  };

  ModalInstanceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'param'];

  function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, param) {
    $scope.ok = function() {
      /* некоторые манипуляции с параметром
       *  в данном случае присваем scope-у родителя, т.е. MainCtrl
       */
      $scope.$parent.param = param;
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('Hello world')">Open me!</button>

    <div ng-bind="param"></div>

       <script type="text/ng-template" id="confirm_delete_item.html">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <h4 class="modal-title">Can I help you?</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">Yes</button>
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">No</button>       
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Update**

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModal'];

function MainCtrl($scope, $uibModal) {
    
  // Ваша функция
  $scope.getHello = function(){
      return 'Hello world';
  };  
    
  $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'confirm_delete_item.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: 'sm',
      resolve: {
        hello: function() {         
          return $scope.getHello;
        }
      }
    });
  };

  ModalInstanceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'hello'];

  function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, hello) {
    $scope.ok = function() {
      // дёргаем вашу функцию
      $scope.$parent.msg = hello();
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>

    <div ng-bind="msg"></div>

       <script type="text/ng-template" id="confirm_delete_item.html">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <h4 class="modal-title">Can I help you?</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">Yes</button>
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">No</button>       
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Можно всё это дело организовать через событийную модель (а-ля PubSub):

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModal'];

function MainCtrl($scope, $uibModal) {

    // подписываемся на событие "onOK"
    $scope.$on('onOK', function ($e, value) {
        // Получаем парметр "value" с "Hello world"
        $scope.msg = value;
    });

    $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'confirm_delete_item.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            size: 'sm'
        });
    };

    ModalInstanceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];

    function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function () {
            /* дёргаем событие "onOK"
               строчку 'Hello world' я указал для наглядности, что можно
               передать некоторые параметры в обработчик события
            */
            $scope.$parent.$broadcast('onOK', 'Hello world');
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>

    <div ng-bind="msg"></div>

       <script type="text/ng-template" id="confirm_delete_item.html">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <h4 class="modal-title">Can I help you?</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">Yes</button>
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">No</button>       
           </div>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! а как вместо передачи параметра `$scope.$parent.param = param;` вызвать функцию у родителя? пытаюсь вот так `$scope.$parent.someFunc(param);` но ошибка `not defined;` функция объявлена в `MainCtrl` как `$scope.someFunc = function(param){ ...}`. И еще вопрос  - имеет ли значение, использовать оба раза для `ok()` и `cancel()` `$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');` или лучше использовать `close()`?

Comment: @Emm: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Emm: Да, можете использовать `$modalInstance.close()`